Symfony 6 Validation Constraints falsely pass
I want to ascertain that a value my api receives is a positive integer and not zero or null
This is my  code for my data object, which is used by the serializer:
class WorkHour
{
[....]
    #[OA\Property(description: 'Arbeitsstunden', type: 'integer')]
    #[Assert\NotEqualTo(value: 0, message: 'Please add number of hours.', groups: ['create', 'update'])]
    #[SerializerGroups(['view', 'create', 'update', 'collection'])]
    public int $hours = 0;
[....]

I also tried out "NotBlank" and "Positive", but the result is the same.
Here is the matching Controller code:

[....]
    #[
        ValidationGroup(['create']),
        Groups(['create']),
        ViewContext(['groups' => ['create'], 'view_link' => true]),
        IsGranted('ROLE_USER', message: 'no right for adding items', statusCode: 403),
        OA\Post(
            operationId: 'workhour_create ',
            description: 'give number of hours',
            summary: 'Arbeitsstunden eintragen',
            requestBody: new OA\RequestBody(
                description: 'WorkHour dto',
                required: true,
                content: new Model(type: WorkHourDto::class)
            ),
            tags: ['WorkHour Data'],
            responses: [
                new OA\Response(
                    response: 201,
                    description: 'Created',
                    content: new Model(type: WorkHourDto::class)
                ),
                new OA\Response(response: 401, description: 'Unauthorized'),
                new OA\Response(response: 403, description: 'Forbidden (access denied)'),
                new OA\Response(response: 422, description: 'Unprocessable Entity'),
                new OA\Response(response: 500, description: 'Internal Server Error'),
            ]
        ),
        Route(path: '', name: 'create', methods: ['POST'])]
    public function create(WorkHourDto $workHourDto): CreatedView
    {

[....]

My phpunit test expects an http status 422, but gets an 201 and happy ever after.
What am I missing here?  How can I achieve that a zero or null is not accepted as a value here?
